# Contact form: Twig_Error_Runtime error upon submission

Tags: form, plugin-contactform

Using the standard P&T contact form, I'm getting the following error when form is submitted (running locally):

```
Twig_Error_Runtime

Impossible to access an attribute ("fromEmail") on a string variable ("") in "_layout" at line 149 (C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php:460)

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\etc\templating\BaseTemplate.php(41): Twig_Template->getAttribute('', 'fromEmail', Array, 'any', false, false)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\storage\runtime\compiled_templates\3\5\352f325e7c58d6329a0dbf553a172b2811c881b391a544d0f295665ec793e2af.php(251): Craft\BaseTemplate->getAttribute('', 'fromEmail', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php(340): __TwigTemplate_352f325e7c58d6329a0dbf553a172b2811c881b391a544d0f295665ec793e2af->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php(314): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\storage\runtime\compiled_templates\2\a\2a1532ab9a7fc5ec6775a274eca668a2af4e295ac7764368b23c762497284924.php(27): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php(340): __TwigTemplate_2a1532ab9a7fc5ec6775a274eca668a2af4e295ac7764368b23c762497284924->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php(314): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php(325): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(293): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\services\TemplatesService.php(223): Twig_Environment->render('404', Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\controllers\BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render('404', Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\controllers\TemplatesController.php(201): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate('404', Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\TemplatesController->actionRenderError()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('renderError')
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(368): CWebApplication->runController('templates/rende...')
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\etc\errors\ErrorHandler.php(264): CErrorHandler->renderError()
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(351): Craft\ErrorHandler->renderError()
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(218): CErrorHandler->renderException()
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\etc\errors\ErrorHandler.php(128): CErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(131): Craft\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\craft\app\framework\base\CApplication.php(740): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
#24 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#25 {main}
```

Running latest Craft Pro 2.4.2700 and latest contact form plugin. What could be causing the error?

Comment: What does your markup look like at "_layout" at line 149"?

Comment: Line 149 was {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}, but I think I found the issue. See below :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the redirect page was not setup. Once I threw up a test page there, the error no longer triggers.

What's odd is that the error page gave little clue (at least to me) as to what was happening.